# AppInsights tracking Request Operation Name differently when using the SDK

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice, telemetry

I've been using the Azure AppInsights plugin on our website (you just turn it on on the app service configuration, no code needed) and was obtaining the request's full operation name that I use for filtering and reporting (I filter on the route id, each id is a different source, we use that for tracking traffic) like in the screenshot below:

Operation Name: **GET /join/social**

[Screenshot of request details with full operation name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udXzp.png)

Recently I had to add custom global properties to the request so I changed to using the SDK instead so I could manually add whatever I needed. Now the requests operation name are coming in like in the screenshot below:

Operation Name: **GET CustomerCoCreation/Join [id]**

[Screenshot of request details with a different operation name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK0P8.png)

It sort of shows now more like a route definition, not showing the **id** anymore, that we so need for our reporting thus rendering every report and custom dashboard that I already created useless.

This is my TelemetryInitializer, pretty standard, just adding the custom property that we wanted (URL referer):

```cs
    public class RefererTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private const string HeaderNameDefault = "Referer";

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public RefererTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            if (httpContextAccessor == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));

            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            if (context == null)
                return;

            if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNameDefault, out var value))
            {
                telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["Referer"] = value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is how I initialize it in the ConfigureServices of my dotnet Core application:

```cs
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RefererTelemetryInitializer>();
```

is there any way to set or configure my initializer to mimic what it was before?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you may add custom properties like below, can it achieve your goal?

```
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["RequestId"] = "customId";
        }
```

Comment: Can it help you, or have any other ideas on it?